# How to delete, not cancel google ads account?

Tags: google-ads

I create a lots of google ads account.

I follow this guide: https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/2424604?co=ADWORDS.IsAWNCustomer%3Dfalse&hl=en

But it only tells you how to cancel google adwords ad accounts. So, these  accounts still show on user profile account list.

I want to delete them, not just cancel them. How can I do this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Once an individual adwords account is canceled, go to **Tools & Settings** > **Setup** > **Account access** and remove your own access to the account.

[image: Google Ads Tools & Settings]

This will remove the account from the list of accounts you have access to.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Note that you go into the cancelled account first before going to Tools & Settings etc

Answer (score 1):

I have one more, create a new dummy ads account with new gmail id. Give all admin rights to that account. From there you can give rights to remove from the original account. Hope its working.

Answer (score 0):

You have to delete your "Google" account in order to delete it. Sadly, google limits the usablity but that's the only choice you have if you're going to "Delete" your google ads account, you're gonna have to Delete yout parents google account.

**To delete your Google Account, follow [these](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32046?hl=en) steps:**

> - Go to your Google Account.
> - On the left navigation Panel, click Data & personalization.
> - On the Download, delete, or make a plan for your data panel, click Delete a service or your account.
> - On the Delete your Google Account panel, click Delete your account.
>
> **Remove other services from your Google Account**
>
> **If you don’t want to delete your entire Google Account, learn how to:**
>
> - [Delete Gmail from your account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/61177)
> - [Remove other Google services](https://myaccount.google.com/permissions?pli=1)
> - [Remove apps with access to your account](https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/sl/pwd?service=adwords&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fads.google.com%2Fum%2Fidentity%3Fsubid%3Dus-en-et-g-aw-a-home-awhp_xin1_signin!o2&hl=en_US&ltmpl=signin&passive=0&skipvpage=true&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin)

Comment: It's sad to hear this.

Comment: I know right because Google always gives people a tough time in different ways.

Answer (score 0):

As of June 2022, if you want to remove a "draft" account, now there is a trash icon near the account name. You can easily delete the linked account and it won't be shown anymore.

[image]